# Hosting a wifi connection

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, lan

I want to host a wifi connection from my computer which is connected through internet via lan cable, so i wanted to know whether i can host it with this usb adapter?

http://cgi.ebay.in/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&Item=250496659669&ssPageName=ADME:B:BSI:IN:1123

Thank You.

Comment: For the archives: that link refers to Belkin Wireless G USB Network Adapter, something like http://www.belkin.com/support/product/?lid=en&pid=F5D7050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for home (personal) use, it will work fine. (basically what Wil said).

If you are planning on sharing your internet connection at work, DON'T!!!! Most companies pay people to keep their network secure. By creating your own WiFi hotspot you have created a hole in the companies network. No only can this be used to gain access to your companies network by hackers it can also get you fired and sued for damages if someone does use the the hole that was created.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to.

If using Windows, there should be a wizard that can do it for you - you just enable internet sharing on the wifi card and it should be able to do all the configuring for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some info for those who get here given the title of the question:

If want to set up your own hotspot, then you might want to have a look at [coova.org](http://www.coova.org/) (derived from the inactive [ChilliSpot](http://www.chillispot.info/)).