# Hosting a wifi connection with Belkin G Wireless usb adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, lan

I have belkin g usb wifi adapter F5D7050, i want to share my computers internet connection which is connected through lan with my mobile (iphone) through wifi, so can anybody help me setting it up?

I have tried google but it is not working for me, may be i am missing some configurations.

I can see my wifi on the phone and connect it, but the above icon which turns to wifi after connecting doesnt change and when i use internet it uses my gprs rather than wifi.

Comment: According to http://superuser.com/questions/42060/hosting-a-wifi-connection it *can* be done. Apparently the question now is: *how?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bought a wifi router.